Can't connect to dev server from mobile
I'm developing a web app and I want to test some features localy before pushing them to the server. Trouble is I can't seem to connect to my locally hosted Flask server from my (Android) phone. I keep getting a timeout error, a connection refused error or a connection aborted error depending on what I try.
I tried a lot of stuff I found here and in other places, including:

Double checking both devices are on the same WiFi
Setting the WiFi to private/trusted instead of public
Changing the host to 0.0.0.0
Changing the host to my local IP
Switching debug mode off
Running the app via cmd instead of launching it as part of __main__ in VS Code
Allowing Python full access through the firewall
Temporarily disabling firewall altogether

None of this has helped. One thing I find weird is that other people talking about this mention a local IP like 256.191.13.95, meanwhile mine is 10.0.0.something. I'm still green as grass when it comes to networking, so am I missing something there?

Are you connecting with the correct port on your phone, the default port for the flask development server is 5000

I believe so, the app runs on 8080 and I tried with and without :8080.

Are you connecting from your phone with http:// or https://? A flask dev server would run on http://

That occurred to me so I tried explicitly prepending http://. Again, nothing changed.

Can you connect to the server from another device or from the server its self with localhost:8080

Yes, when it's running on 127.0.0.1:8080 everything works just fine in a browser on the same device. If I use my actual local IP I can connect (only on the same device) but sessions don't seem to persist between requests.

There are different IPs associated with the device you are running the dev server from. localhost (aka. 127.0.0.1) is only accessible on the device you are hosting on. Instead, the one you want is the LAN one, which is local to your network. You can find yours by going to WiFi settings. It will start with 10.0.0.xx.
In your Flask server you will want to set the hostname to 0.0.0.0. This will bind it to every IP available to your server and will ensure that you can use it anywhere in your network. Finally, using the IP you found above in settings, enter that into your phone with :8080 after it.
app.run(host=“0.0.0.0”, port=8080)

